# Refreshing cells in a table/tree

Tags: javafx, tree, refresh

I am looking for a way to trigger refresh on a single cell in the TableView or a tree.
I know I can link property with TableCell and update this property but I do not want to create large number of properties this way. I'm looking from opposite way.
I want to have method on my table wrapper: 
`tableWrapper.refresh(T rowItem, String attributeNameOfMyItem)`. Is there a way to achieve this goal?
Can I access from such place specific `TreeTableCell` to call its method updateItem() which in turn update presentation of the cell?
Or the only way is to link through property TreeTableCell and update the property?

```
package ks.javafx.table.refresh;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javafx.scene.paint.Color;

public class Validator
{
    private Map person2col = new HashMap();
    private Color[] colors = new Color[] { Color.RED, Color.ORANGE, Color.BLUE, Color.VIOLET, Color.MAGENTA };

    public Validator()
    {
    }

    public void forceValidation(Person person)
    {
        int length = person.getLastName().length();
        Color color = colors[length % colors.length];
        person2col.put(person, color);
    }

    public Color getValidation(Person person)
    {
        return person2col.get(person);
    }
}
```

```
package ks.javafx.table.refresh;

import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import ks.javafx.util.ColorUtil;

public class EditingCell extends TableCell<Person, String>
{
    private Validator validator;
    private TextField textField;

    public EditingCell(Validator validator)
    {
        this.validator = validator;
    }

    @Override
    public void startEdit()
    {
        if(!isEmpty())
        {
            super.startEdit();
            createTextField();
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(textField);
            textField.selectAll();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void cancelEdit()
    {
        super.cancelEdit();

        setText(getItem());
        setGraphic(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty)
    {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if(empty)
        {
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);
        }
        else
        {
            if(isEditing())
            {
                if(textField != null)
                {
                    textField.setText(getString());
                }
                setText(null);
                setGraphic(textField);
            }
            else
            {
                setText(getString());
                int index = getIndex();
                Person person = getTableView().getItems().get(index);

                Color color = validator.getValidation(person);
                // color = Color.ALICEBLUE;
                if(color != null)
                {
                    String webColor = ColorUtil.toWebString(color);
                    setStyle("-fx-background-color:" + webColor + ";");
                }
                setGraphic(null);
            }
        }
    }

    private void createTextField()
    {
        textField = new TextField(getString());
        textField.setMinWidth(this.getWidth() - this.getGraphicTextGap() * 2);
        textField.focusedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>()
        {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> arg0, Boolean arg1, Boolean arg2)
            {
                if(!arg2)
                {
                    commitEdit(textField.getText());
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private String getString()
    {
        return getItem() == null ? "" : getItem().toString();
    }
}
```

```
package ks.javafx.table.refresh;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;

public class Person
{
    private final SimpleStringProperty firstName;
    private final SimpleStringProperty lastName;
    private final SimpleStringProperty email;

    public Person(String fName, String lName, String email)
    {
        this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(fName);
        this.lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(lName);
        this.email = new SimpleStringProperty(email);
    }

    public String getFirstName()
    {
        return firstName.get();
    }

    public void setFirstName(String fName)
    {
        firstName.set(fName);
    }

    public String getLastName()
    {
        return lastName.get();
    }

    public void setLastName(String fName)
    {
        lastName.set(fName);
    }

    public String getEmail()
    {
        return email.get();
    }

    public void setEmail(String fName)
    {
        email.set(fName);
    }
}
```

```
package ks.javafx.table.refresh;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.CellEditEvent;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class RefreshTableApp extends Application
{
    private Validator validator = new Validator();

    private TableView<Person> table = new TableView<Person>();
    private static final Person PERSON_A = new Person("Anna", "Rogowska", "anna.rogowska@example.com");
    private final ObservableList<Person> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(new Person("Jacob", "Smith",
          "jacob.smith@example.com"), new Person("Isabella", "Johnson", "isabella.johnson@example.com"),
          new Person("Ethan", "Williams", "ethan.williams@example.com"), new Person("Emma", "Jones",
                "emma.jones@example.com"), new Person("Michael", "Brown", "michael.brown@example.com"),
          PERSON_A);
    final HBox hb = new HBox();

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage)
    {
        Scene scene = new Scene(new Group());
        stage.setTitle("Table View Sample");
        stage.setWidth(450);
        stage.setHeight(550);

        final Label label = new Label("Address Book");
        label.setFont(new Font("Arial", 20));

        table.setEditable(true);
        Callback<TableColumn, TableCell> cellFactory = new Callback<TableColumn, TableCell>()
        {
            @Override
            public TableCell call(TableColumn p)
            {
                return new EditingCell(validator);
            }
        };

        TableColumn firstNameCol = new TableColumn("First Name");
        firstNameCol.setMinWidth(100);
        firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("firstName"));
        firstNameCol.setCellFactory(cellFactory);
        firstNameCol.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<Person, String>>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(CellEditEvent<Person, String> t)
            {
                t.getTableView().getItems().get(t.getTablePosition().getRow()).setFirstName(t.getNewValue());
            }
        });

        TableColumn lastNameCol = new TableColumn("Last Name");
        lastNameCol.setMinWidth(100);
        lastNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("lastName"));
        lastNameCol.setCellFactory(cellFactory);
        lastNameCol.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<Person, String>>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(CellEditEvent<Person, String> t)
            {
                t.getTableView().getItems().get(t.getTablePosition().getRow()).setLastName(t.getNewValue());
            }
        });

        TableColumn emailCol = new TableColumn("Email");
        emailCol.setMinWidth(200);
        emailCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("email"));
        emailCol.setCellFactory(cellFactory);
        emailCol.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<Person, String>>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(CellEditEvent<Person, String> t)
            {
                t.getTableView().getItems().get(t.getTablePosition().getRow()).setEmail(t.getNewValue());
            }
        });

        table.setItems(data);
        table.getColumns().addAll(firstNameCol, lastNameCol, emailCol);

        final TextField addFirstName = new TextField();
        addFirstName.setPromptText("First Name");
        addFirstName.setMaxWidth(firstNameCol.getPrefWidth());
        final TextField addLastName = new TextField();
        addLastName.setMaxWidth(lastNameCol.getPrefWidth());
        addLastName.setPromptText("Last Name");
        final TextField addEmail = new TextField();
        addEmail.setMaxWidth(emailCol.getPrefWidth());
        addEmail.setPromptText("Email");

        final Button addButton = new Button("Add");
        addButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent e)
            {
                data.add(new Person(addFirstName.getText(), addLastName.getText(), addEmail.getText()));
                addFirstName.clear();
                addLastName.clear();
                addEmail.clear();
            }
        });

        hb.getChildren().addAll(addFirstName, addLastName, addEmail, addButton);
        hb.setSpacing(3);

        final VBox vbox = new VBox();
        vbox.setSpacing(5);
        vbox.setPadding(new Insets(10, 0, 0, 10));
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(label, table, hb, createButtons());

        ((Group) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().addAll(vbox);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

    }

    private Node createButtons()
    {
        Button but = new Button("validate last person");
        but.setOnAction(e -> {
            validator.forceValidation(data.get(data.size() - 1));
        });


        FlowPane pane = new FlowPane(but);
        return pane;
    }

}
```

```
package ks.javafx.util;

import javafx.scene.paint.Color;

public final class ColorUtil
{
    /**
     * Translates provided {@link Color} to web string (#RRGGBB).
     * @param aColor
     * @return
     */
    public static String toWebString(final Color aColor)
    {
        final int r = (int) Math.round(aColor.getRed() * 255.0);
        final int g = (int) Math.round(aColor.getGreen() * 255.0);
        final int b = (int) Math.round(aColor.getBlue() * 255.0);
        final String res = String.format("#%02x%02x%02x", r, g, b);
        return res;
    }

}
```

Comment: You've indicated you know the intended way to do this, with JavaFX properties. Can you explain why you don't want to do it that way, with a code example?

Comment: It would difficult to extract the code since it is part of a really large application. I'll try to explain. 1. TreeCell shall not known about functionality called validation. 2. Validation provides some tableUpdater. Its task is to listen for changes in validation (a user change value of a cell and this should be immediately changed, a user change value of a cell and after validating on the server side after some time validation is changed). When the change happens and this affects specified updater must force table to repaint since attached mechanism must recount and  add decorations.

Comment: So basically I do not what to clatter TableCell to know about the need to refresh. I also worried about large number of properties which I need to create in TableCell and the mechanism which updates them individually.

Comment: Provide a [MCVE]. (Don't provide your whole application, just create a new application from scratch that does just enough to demonstrate the problem.) The description is too hard (for me at least) to follow. In general though, your cell should observe the properties that change when it needs to refresh.

Comment: I added some sample. I hope I didn't miss anything. This is only sample. Basically when you press button (RefreshTableApp.java) Validation.forceValidatoin() is called with last Person. Then we should update cell (EditingCell).